# Apache2: ReWrite rule behaving strangely

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.2, rewrite

I have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
<Directory /home/eamorr/sites/example.com/www>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                Options -Indexes
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all

                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?uname=$1 [R,L]
</Directory>
```

When I go to http://example.com/Eamorr, http://example.com/home/eamorr/sites/example.com/www/index.php?uname=Eamorr appears in the address bar!

But I want http://example.com/index.php?uname=Eamorr to appear in the address bar!!!

(I need to parse the URL in javascript in index.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Directory>` directive can be only used in server config or virtual host, **not** in `.htaccess` file.

If you use:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?uname=$1 [R,L]
```

the per-directory prefix (`/home/eamorr/sites/example.com/www`) is automatically added to the substitution. So remove the `<Directory>` directive and put a slash at the begining:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?uname=$1 [R,L]
```

it will work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks so much for that. I'm totally clueless when it comes to anything other than bog standard Apache rules...